# Generate temporary pdf and display it in object tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, pdf, itext

I want to generate a pdf file using the iTextSharp, then I want to dispaly this file in object tag.
Here my code to generate the pdf:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);    

    pdfDoc.Open();

    Paragraph Title = new Paragraph("New Paragraph");
    pdfDoc.Add(Title);

    pdfDoc.Close(); 

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +

                                   "filename=sample.pdf");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);

    Response.End();
```

but this code is generating a pdf file and show save/open dialogue which I don't want. I want it to be generated and then be displayed in the object tag without the dialogue and without to save it on my folders.

Comment: Can you try to change the "attachment" in `content-disposition` to "inline"?

Comment: There's a similar question that I answered years ago here but I can't find it. The gist of it was that when a client sends an HTTP request, the server is allowed to send one and only one response. You can send the PDF or you can send the HTML that contains the `<object>` tag but you can't send both (although you could try a data URI I guess). So that's the problem you need to solve. You can do some ajax magic or you could make an HTTP endpoint of some sort that generates a PDF and you point your object tag at that in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant line is the following:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.pdf");
```

By setting `content-disposition` to *attachment*, you specify that the browser should require some user interaction (see this [link](http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml) for details and other possible values).

If you change the value to *inline*, the browser should display the element as you desire:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=sample.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with "inline", Thank you all